# Is a proper ideal of a polynomial ring (on a field) still proper in the polynomial ring on a field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $\mathbb{K}$ be its algebraic closure. Let $p_1,p_2,...,p_k \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ be such that the ideal generated by these elements in the ring $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ is proper. Does it hold that the ideal generated by $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ in the ring $\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ is still proper?

The statement is true whenever $k=1$ (and $\mathbb{K}$ is not required to be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}$): if the ideal generated by $p\in \mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ in the ring $\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ is the whole ring, then there is $q \in \mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $pq=1$. Since $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and $p, q$ are invertible, it is the case that $p,q \in \mathbb{K}$. Therefore $p \in \mathbb{F}$ and then $q \in \mathbb{F}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $I=(p_1,...,p_k)$ is a proper ideal $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$. Let $J$ be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ containing $I$. Then $J=(q_1,...,q_m)$, for some $q_1,...,q_m$ in $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$, and we can consider the ideal of $\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ generated by $q_1,...,q_m$. Let it be $J'$.

Let $\Phi$ be the map $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n] \to \mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]/J'$ such that $f \mapsto f + J'$. Since $J \subset J'$, $J \subset \ker(\Phi)$. Being $J$ maximal and being $\ker(\Phi)$ an ideal, $\ker(\Phi)=J$. Therefore there is an injective map $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]/J \to \mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]/J'$. Notice that $\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]/J'$ cannot be trivial, because $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]/J$ is not trivial. Therefore $J'$ is proper. Since the ideal generated by $p_1,...,p_n$ in $\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ is contained in $J'$, it must be proper.

Comment: This is wrong: you cannot conclude that $\ker(\Phi)=J$ because it could be the whole ring instead.  You must use something special about the fact that these are polynomial rings, since the analogous result for an arbitrary extension of rings is not true.  (For instance, no nonzero ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ remains proper when you extend it to $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I leave this answer for readers who may have a similar idea and may fall into a mistake. Thank you for your comment :).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, and this is just linear algebra.  Suppose we are looking for polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_k$ of degree at most $m$ such that $\sum f_ip_i=1$.  This equation can be expanded out into a system of linear equations in the coefficients of the $f_i$.  If this system of linear equations has no solution in $\mathbb{F}$, it also has no solution in any extension of $\mathbb{F}$ (since we can determine whether there is a solution by Gaussian elimination, which uses only the field operations).

Or, from a more sophisticated perspective, let $R=\mathbb{F}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, $S=\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, $I=(p_1,\dots,p_k)\subseteq R$, and $J=(p_1,\dots,p_k)\subseteq S$.  We then have canonical isomorphisms $S\cong\mathbb{K}\otimes_\mathbb{F} R$ and $$S/J=S/IS\cong S\otimes_R R/I\cong \mathbb{K}\otimes_\mathbb{F} R/I.$$  If $I$ is proper, then $R/I$ is a nontrivial $\mathbb{F}$-vector space, so $S/J\cong \mathbb{K}\otimes_\mathbb{F} R/I$ is a nontrivial $\mathbb{K}$-vector space, so $J$ is proper.

Comment: Very nice! Your "more sophisticated perspective" proof seems to work for any faithfully flat morphism of rings $\mathbb F\to \mathbb K$. Interesting.